# Multiprocessing Pool in python2 not working

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, flask, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to put call to 3 other APIs in the form of multiprocessing from an API hosted on 8080. Here is the code I am using (python 3.4):

```
import requests, json
from flask import Flask, request
from concurrent import futures

def getRequest(*args):
    return requests.get(args[0],params = args[1])

process = futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(3)
some_text =  open('lines.txt').read() # some text
params = {'text': some_text}
url1 = 'http://localhost:8081' # api2
url2 = 'http://localhost:8082' # api1
url3 = 'http://localhost:8083' # api3
g = process.map(getRequest, [[url1,params], [url2,params], [url3, params]])
```

Above code snippet sits in a flask app running on port 8080. I can connect to port 8080 and even the requests are being sent to ports 8081,8082, 8083 in parallel but there have been some data type mismatch between these APIs. It automatically changes `json.dumps(arg[0],arg[1])`'s data to some form.

All other APIs work fine individually.

This is the error that I am getting:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jul/2015 21:58:18] "GET /?%7B%22article%22:%20%22American%20Profile%20-%20American%20Profile%20Celebrates%20The%20Intriguing%20People,%20Places%20And%20Things%20In%20Hometowns%20Across%20The%20Country%20Along%20With%20Features%20On%20Music,%20Film,%20TV,%20Seasonal%20Recipes,%20Health%20And%20Family%20Finance.%20Get%20every%20new%20post%20delivered%20to%20your%20Inbox.%20Join%20184%20other%20followers%20%5Cn%22%7D HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/prateekgupta/Desktop/project-annie/phrase_extraction/code/getNounsAndNounPhrases.py", line 18, in getKeywords
    vals = eval(request.data)
File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

This is the API on port 8081 (python 2.7):

```
# API
app=Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getSomething():
    vals = dict(request.args)['key'][0] # its a hack. idk when to use args. ideally i will like to pass json and get json
    return json.dumps(some_function(vals), indent=4) + '\n'


# start your app here
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port =8081)
```

I have tried different configurations with the arguments but of no use.

Answer (score 0):

`eval` is not the opposite of `json.dumps`, `json.loads` is (`eval` treats the payload as Python code and JSON is not a proper subset of Python).

Change your `getSomething` handler to use `vals = json.loads(request.data)` (or even better, `vals = request.get_json(force=true)`) and things should work as expected.

Comment: I am not sure if that is really the case. I changed the above code by using args. Its not clear to me when to use args and when to use get_json(). It seems to me like a hack as of now.